# Explicit entire functions with infinitely many prescribed values

Tags: cv.complex-variables

A set $S$ of entire functions $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is called interpolating if for any sequence $a_1<a_2<\dots$ tending to infinity and any sequence $b_1, b_2, \dots$ there exists $f\in S$ such that $f(a_i)=b_i$.

Is the closure of polynomial and exponential functions under composition an interpolating set?

Comment: The closure of polynomials is all entire functions (Taylor series), or what do you mean by *closure* if not taken with respect to locally uniform convergence?

Comment: @ChristianRemling ... The phrase here is "closure under composition".  Not a topological type closure.

Comment: I think your answer is "no"...  If we want $f(n) = \log n$ for $n = 1,2,3,\dots$ I'm guessing that none of your compositions can have this rate of growth.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "no". Gerald Edgar has already suggested to look at sequences that grow "too slowly". But in fact, one can also construct sequences that grow "too fast".

**Lemma.** Let $C$ be the closure of complex polynomials and $\exp$ under composition. Then for any $f\in C$ there is a natural number $n$ such that $$|f(z)|\leq \exp^n(|z|)$$ holds for all $z$ with sufficiently large absolute value. Here $\exp^n=\exp(\exp(\dotso))$ denotes the $n$-fold iteration of $\exp$.

**Proof.** Let $C'\subseteq C$ be the subset where this holds. $C'$ clearly contains all polynomials and the exponential function. Furthermore, if $f\in C'$, then also $p(f)\in C'$ for all polynomials $p$, and $\exp(f)\in C'$. Indeed, $|f(z)|\leq \exp^n(|z|)$ for all sufficiently large $|z|$ implies that  $|p(f(z))|\leq \exp^{n+1}(|z|)$ and $|\exp(f(z))|\leq \exp^{n+1}(|z|)$ for all sufficiently large $|z|$. Thus $C'=C$.  $\square$

To get an explicit counterexample, consider the sequence $a_n=n$ and take $b_n=\exp^n(n)$. By the lemma, there can't be any $f\in C$ with $f(a_n)=b_n$.